# Jquery UI Sortable RowSpan inside Table issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery UI sorting widget to sort table rows. I have simple rows as well as group of rowsin my table I have used rowspan to accomplish grouping of rows.

Simple Rows : Jill, Smith, 50
Group of Rows : Eve, Jackson, 94,

Simple Sorting works really well but when I try to drag a row which contains group of rows its not working. I need some inputs to know where I am going wrong to drag the group of rows.

Check my Js Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rickjackson/3Lbfd8ch/1/

I have written the below code to enable sorting in my code

```
var fixHelper = function (e, ui) { ui.children().each(function () 
{
 $(this).width($(this).width()); }); return ui; 
};
$("#t01 tbody").sortable({ helper: fixHelper }).disableSelection();
```

I need your inputs where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: It could be that you need to have the "Eve" row and the other three rows that have hidden td (as the first column) inside one table row, which means that you need put all those inside another table. It looks like those three rows aren't recognized by jQueryUI. Well, I'm no jQueryUI specialist so I'm not 100% sure what restrictions the sortable function has. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Jyrkim... for your help... Can we body please help me out on this !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at this and I managed to get it working, once I created two nested tables for the row that had four rows for columns 2 and 3.

```
<table id="t01" style="width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody class="ui-sortable">
        <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td><div class="columnMargin">Smith</div></td>
             <td><div class="columnMargin">50</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-sortable-handle" data-multiple="true">
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>
                <table class="multipleRows">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-style:solid">Jackson</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lightblue;">
                            <input name="cell1" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lightblue;">
                            <input name="cell1" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lightblue;">
                            <input name="cell2" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="multipleRows">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-style:solid">94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lightblue;">
                            <input name="cell1" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lightblue;">
                            <input name="cell1" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lightblue;">
                            <input name="cell2" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td><div class="columnMargin">Smith</div></td>
            <td><div class="columnMargin">50</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td><div class="columnMargin">Jackson</div></td>
            <td><div class="columnMargin">94</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also changed the jQueryUI part to use [items](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) options with rows that have class `.ui-sortable-handle`:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#t01 tbody").sortable({
         items: ".ui-sortable-handle"
     }).disableSelection();
 });
```

I guess there is still some fine tuning left with the CSS styles, but the Sortable part is nevertheless working. So I hope you find it okay :-) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/3Lbfd8ch/2/)